# How to --query via az rest --method

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-rest-api

Although I'm new to JMESPath, but even so, feeling extra dumbfounded that none of the docs I've pulled have a relative working example that I readily use. For example, [from the Query Azure CLI command output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest), there is a disregard for how the returned output is wrapped in the `value` key —as explained via an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12472); but even when trying that syntax I don't get any positive results.

What I need to do is return the set that resembles the following:

```
az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/ --query "[?contains(displayName,'Administrator')]" --output json
```

The expected return should be:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryRoles",
  "value": [
    {
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "displayName": "Foo Administrator",
      "id": "09fe6ef5-4af5-650d-a2e5-63895bba8f16",
      "otherId": "4d2ac1ba-3253-41a0-a1f9-a3e0f568773a"
    },
     {
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "displayName": "Bar Administrator",
      "id": "1602300e-a17b-42d0-97a2-e3d0f0c1fa14",
      "otherId": "fda7a751-a60a-444b-974d-02352ee8fa1c"
    },
    {
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "displayName": "Foobar Service Administrator",
      "id": "f94ad3a3-5e69-4638-b47d-e4df2d831dc8",
      "otherId": "59091246-12e8-4a86-aa5a-066175b1a7a8"
    },
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

... so per the Microsoft [Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) documentation, the `contains` string operator is not supported on any resources. But I was able to pipe out my array via `jq`:

```
az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/ \
    | jq '.value[] | select(.displayName | contains("Administrator"))'
```